# Is it safe to use GLKViewController in a portion of the screen only?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, opengl-es, glkit

I remember that UIViewControllers were only for fullscreen.
Is GLKViewController safe to use in a portion of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

It's true that UIViewControllers are meant for fullscreen only, but that doesn't mean it's not possible.  If you can get it to work go ahead!  However, in a case like that, it would probably be better to just put a GLKView in the corner and manage it from whatever UIViewController is controlling the superview.

Comment: You can force a render from your UIViewController.  Depending upon the type of application and your GPU load, this can be completely acceptable. For things like image processing where you need every frame, this approach can even be preferable.  Another question on StackOverflow mentioned that Apple even seems to suggest a UIViewController for these on-demand render situations. (I have not seen any reference backing that statement.)